# JavaScript if() case in CloudCode.

Tags: javascript, function, boolean, parse-platform

In this code im trying to get the Object for the caller of this method, using his unique username. If the object exists -> update it, of not -> create one. 
However: my boolean value "found" is never changed. Even though, it must be changed after my Query. Because of this my if statement is never used and therefore no object created. 
Does anyone know why?

To my knowledge its ok changing a global value from within a function.

```
Parse.Cloud.define("updateUserGeneral", function(request, response){

var UserGeneralObject = Parse.Object.extend("userGeneral");
var userGeneralNew = new UserGeneralObject();
var found = false;


var username = request.params.username;
var private_name = request.params.private_name;
var intentions = request.params.intentions;
var gender = request.params.gender;
var looking_gender = request.params.lookinggender;
var age = request.params.age;
var min_age = request.params.min_age;
var max_age = request.params.max_age;
var radius = request.params.radius;
var applyradius = request.params.applyradius;


   var query2 = new Parse.Query("userGeneral");
   query2.equalTo("username", username);
      query2.first({
     success: function(userGeneral){
            if(userGeneral!=null){
                found = true;
                userGeneral.set("private_name", private_name);
                userGeneral.set("intentions", intentions);
                userGeneral.set("gender", gender);
                userGeneral.set("lookinggender", looking_gender);
                userGeneral.set("age", age);
                userGeneral.set("max_age", max_age);
                userGeneral.set("min_age", min_age);
                userGeneral.set("radius", radius);
                userGeneral.set("applyradius", applyradius );
                userGeneral.save();
                response.success("Succesfully saved userGeneral");      
            }else{
                found = false;
            }

     },
     error: function(error){
         found = false; 
     }
   });

      if(found == false){
          userGeneralNew.set("username", username);
          userGeneralNew.set("private_name", private_name);
          userGeneralNew.set("intentions", intentions);
          userGeneralNew.set("gender", gender);
          userGeneralNew.set("lookinggender", looking_gender);
          userGeneralNew.set("age", age);
          userGeneralNew.set("max_age", max_age);
          userGeneralNew.set("min_age", min_age);
          userGeneralNew.set("applyradius", applyradius);
          userGeneralNew.set("radius", radius);
          userGeneralNew.set("lookingForChat", 0);
          userGeneralNew.set("lookingForInvitation", 1);
          userGeneralNew.set("userHasChat", 0);

            userGeneralNew.save(null, {
                success: function () {
                    console.log("Save ok");
                    response.success("Succesfully saved userGeneral New");

                },
                error: function (error) {
                    console.log("Save failed");
                    response.error("Failed saving userGeneral New");

                }
            });
      }

});
```

Comment: Is `query2.first` asyncronous?

Comment: do you mean if it is in a new thread? i´m guessing yes. if so: how do i access the standart variable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`success: function(userGeneral){` is a callback function. In this case the code will most likely finish before you update the variable found. So the following code will run before the success function runs.

```
if(found == false){
      userGeneralNew.set("username", username);
      userGeneralNew.set("private_name", private_name);
      userGeneralNew.set("intentions", intentions);
      userGeneralNew.set("gender", gender);
      userGeneralNew.set("lookinggender", looking_gender);
      userGeneralNew.set("age", age);
      userGeneralNew.set("max_age", max_age);
      userGeneralNew.set("min_age", min_age);
      userGeneralNew.set("applyradius", applyradius);
      userGeneralNew.set("radius", radius);
      userGeneralNew.set("lookingForChat", 0);
      userGeneralNew.set("lookingForInvitation", 1);
      userGeneralNew.set("userHasChat", 0);

        userGeneralNew.save(null, {
            success: function () {
                console.log("Save ok");
                response.success("Succesfully saved userGeneral New");

            },
            error: function (error) {
                console.log("Save failed");
                response.error("Failed saving userGeneral New");

            }
        });
  }
```